# Project Tango - Unity SDK - Depth Points - Apparently 2 "modes" of depth - High quality and low quality?

Tags: depth, google-project-tango

I have noticed, when working with the Project Tango Unity SDK for depth points, that usually I will first get a low density cloud of points (<6k points) when looking at a scene, and then seemingly randomly, it will jump up in Quality to be 12k+ points - same scene, same lighting, same position.

Has anyone else experienced this and have any idea about what is happening during this transition?

Comment: Hi, could you try to [this](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/hardware/depth-test), see if you have the same behavior when facing the wall.

Comment: Jason:  I had a "loaner" device I picked up at the Game Dev conference 2 weeks ago that was having this behavior.  In the mean time, I have received my formal replacement device (on Friday) and this new device is not displaying this behavior at all.  It was likely an issue with the loaner device (Johnny 40) that is boxed up and heading back to your support team this week. :)